# Is `git branch` using `less` a recent change? Or is `less` behaving differently recently?

Tags: git, less

Appologies for the vague title.

I frequently execute `git branch` throughout the day, and it seems at some point recently (perhaps in the past month?) the behavior has changed.  I recall previously `git branch` would print the list of branches and immediately return to a prompt -- however it now appears to be printing the branches *within `less`*, and requiring me to press `Esc` before returning to the command prompt.

I'm uncertain if this is a change to `git branch` itself, or perhaps my default `less` flags -- or possible some other factor.

I've observed this on:

- Debian bullseye, git 2.30.2
- macOS Montegery, git 2.34.1

In both cases `less`' default flags haven't been customized by me, and are:
`LESS="-g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4"`

And running `git branch` in any git repo will print the branches as expected, with less's summary of `lines 1-X/X (END)` at the bottom of the console.  Pressing `h` shows the `less` help prompt--confirming it is `less` that's being used.

Is this a recent change?  Is there a git option to avoid using less--or a `less` option/flag to have it automatically exit if there's less than one screen of data?

Comment: Maybe: you just got enough branches to trigger the pager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch` defaults to using a pager since version 2.16.

You can configure that by changing `pager.branch`, *e.g.*

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

or on an ad-hoc basis by adding the `-P` (`--no-pager`) option.

`less` does have an option to exit if the data it is asked to display fits on a single screen, `-F`. When the `LESS` environment variable is *not* set, `git` sets it to `FRX` by default, which includes this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks!  Sounds like the change is actually a couple years old -- I wonder if I just started noticing it because of some other variable.  Regardless, the config setting or the less flag are exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I use `git branch -avv` under emacs shell windows a lot. The above solution is permanent. If you are seeking a temporary solution, you can execute `export PAGER=cat` in shell and git branch will use cat rather than less. This change will be reverted and the normal behavior will return when your current shell dies.

Comment: Or just run `git` as `PAGER=cat git branch -avv` (or `git -c core.pager=cat branch -avv` or `git -c pager.branch=0 branch -avv` or `git branch -avv | cat` as `less` stops paginating when its stdout doesn't go to  a tty, git may also skip running a pager altogether (also affects colouring though))